# Some CGAL examples (e.g. Jet Smoothing and Normal Orientation) fail to compile

Tags: c++, cmake, cgal

I am currently working on a project in which, using some of the CGAL algorithms for point set processing would be highly advantageous.

Amongst others, I need to get the jet smoothing algorithm running - here shown by the example from:
http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_processing_3/

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/jet_smooth_point_set.h>
#include <vector>

// types
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point;

int main(void)
{
  // generate point set
  std::vector<Point> points;
  points.push_back(Point( 0.0, 0.0, 0.001));
  points.push_back(Point(-0.1,-0.1, 0.002));
  points.push_back(Point(-0.1,-0.2, 0.001));
  points.push_back(Point(-0.1, 0.1, 0.002));
  points.push_back(Point( 0.1,-0.1, 0.000));
  points.push_back(Point( 0.1, 0.2, 0.001));
  points.push_back(Point( 0.2, 0.0, 0.002));
  points.push_back(Point( 0.2, 0.1, 0.000));
  points.push_back(Point( 0.0,-0.1, 0.001));

  // Smoothing.
  const unsigned int nb_neighbors = 8; // default is 24 for real-life point sets
  CGAL::jet_smooth_point_set(points.begin(), points.end(), nb_neighbors);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When compiling this (using CMake), I am hit with the following errors:

```
   error: no matching function for call to ‘jet_smooth_point_set(std::vector<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> >::iterator, std::vector<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> >::iterator, const unsigned int&)’
   CGAL::jet_smooth_point_set(points.begin(), points.end(), nb_neighbors);

   jet_smooth_point_set.h:177:1: note: candidate: template<class Concurrency_tag, class InputIterator, class PointPMap, class Kernel, class SvdTraits> void CGAL::jet_smooth_point_set(InputIterator, InputIterator, PointPMap, unsigned int, const Kernel&, unsigned int, unsigned int)

   note:   candidate expects 7 arguments, 3 provided
   CGAL::jet_smooth_point_set(points.begin(), points.end(), nb_neighbors);
```

The error seems to imply that the function is not specified in the included header file? Yet it seems that the header has been located correctly?

The same issue arises in the examples shipped with the CGAL repository.

My set up is Ubuntu 15.10, GCC 5.2.1, CMake 3.2.2, and I have produced this error with CGAL 4.6 from the Ubuntu repositories and the CGAL 4.8-beta compiled from the Github repository.

For what it is worth, the outlier removal-example as well as the input/output-examples compile and execute correctly.

I feel somewhat stuck at this point and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Parallel version will be added in CGAL-4.8. See [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CGAL/cgal/master/Point_set_processing_3/examples/Point_set_processing_3/jet_smoothing_example.cpp) updated example. The code should be working with 4.7 and earlier however.

Comment: Thank you; yes, I have stumbled across the parallel version of the example. However, as pointed out below, the problem seems to be that I have not managed to include Eigen3 in my compilation of CGAL.

Comment: Then if you're using cmake you're missing `  find_package(Eigen3 3.1.0)  
  if (EIGEN3_FOUND)
    include( ${EIGEN3_USE_FILE} ) endif()`. If not but your compiler knows where to find eigen, simply define `CGAL_EIGEN3_ENABLED`, as documented [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Jet_fitting_3/classCGAL_1_1Monge__via__jet__fitting.html)

Comment: Thank you - as you can see in the comments for the answer below, I am already including Eigen3, and my compiler does indeed locate the Eigen3_use_file. I have also experimented with defining CGAL_EIGEN3_ENABLED. It leads to the following error, when compiling the example in question:

CGAL/Kernel_23/include/CGAL/Dimension.h:28:22: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory

, which to me implies that EIgen3 has in fact not been compiled correctly?

Comment: Eigen is a header only library, you simply need to add it to the include directories of your compiler

Comment: Once again, thank you for your interest. As you can see in the transcript in the comments to the answer below, cmake manages to locate the UseEigen3-file and the path to the include-directory (for me: /usr/include/eigen3). Yet in the end, Eigen3 seems to not be included properly in the compilation. I have tried using your suggested code, and I seem to be making an error in the syntax of include. I get: include called with wrong number of arguments.  include() only takes one file.

Comment: You should put these lines after the instruction `include( ${CGAL_USE_FILE} )`. If it is still not working trying printing `${EIGEN3_USE_FILE}` using the `message` command.

Comment: As written below, I have now managed to get things working by including the eigen3 in both my project and my CGAL-compilation. Thank you very much for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked at `<CGAL/jet_smooth_point_set.h>` in git, located at

[jet_smooth_point_set.h](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Point_set_processing_3/include/CGAL/jet_smooth_point_set.h)

I have found out that the 5-parameter overload with the last 2 parameters being default, defined at line 320,

```
template <typename Concurrency_tag,
          typename InputIterator>
void jet_smooth_point_set(
    InputIterator first, ///< iterator over the first input point
    InputIterator beyond, ///< past-the-end iterator
    unsigned int k, ///< number of neighbors.
    const unsigned int degree_fitting = 2,
    const unsigned int degree_monge = 2)
```

being used in the example code, is surrounded by the following `#ifdef` at line 263:

```
#if defined(CGAL_EIGEN3_ENABLED) || defined(CGAL_LAPACK_ENABLED)
```

Thus I have concluded that CGAL has been built without the above two libraries, Eigen3 and LAPACK. Try rebuilding CGAL with with support for either of those (note the `||` conditional operator in the `#ifdef`). To do that, install the corresponding package along with the `devel` package (I'm a RedHat guy, so don't know how Ubuntu splits dev and non-dev packages). You want to have the headers for those libraries installed to compile CGAl against them. Then, re-run cmake, make sure it finds the libraries (invoke `ccmake` or watch cmake configuration output closely for e.g. "found Eigen3") and rebuild CGAL.

Comment: I have libeigen3-dev installed (v. 3.2.5: CGAL requires 3.1 or greater), but as you concluded, I did not manually include this in CMakeLists.txt. I did this using "INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})", where EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR is passed from the command-line argument "-DEIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/eigen3" (the directory of signature_of_eigen3_matrix_library). After testing with a simple IF-statement, it seems the path is located correctly. 

Yet the error remains, when compiling the example in the original post with my newly compiled version of CGAL.

Comment: Are you talking about your own project's (i.e. this example) CMakeLists.txt or the CGAL source tree's one? What I meant, is that you want to rebuild the actual CGAL source tree with Eigen or Lapack enabled. At least that's what the code suggests. Check the output `ccmake .` in the CGAL's build dir to see if Eigen3 is being enabled and built.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified that I am talking about the CMakelists.txt in CGAL's source tree. According to ccmake, WITH_Eigen3 was not set to ON, so I am guessing, you are right.

However, after changing this, cmake produces the following text regarding Eigen3:
-- Eigen3 has been preconfigured:
--   UseEigen3-file:      UseEigen3
--   Eigen3 include:      /usr/include/eigen3
--   Eigen3 libraries:    
--   Eigen3 definitions:

Yet the error seems to persist. Did I not include the libraries properly?

Comment: Well, since I also study CG and am about to invest into learning CGAL, let me try to reproduce your setup and report back in a day.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated!

Comment: After playing around some more, I realised that I can get things working by adding the same parts to my CMakeLists.txt for my project as well as for my CGAL-compilation. Thank you very much for your inputs.

Comment: I decided that your comment helped me sufficiently to be considered the "right" answer, yes. Ultimately, my problem was that I hadn't compiled everything with Eigen3, which was indeed the issue, you pointed out.

And your clue as to why I failed to find the right function template was - in hindsight - pretty close to the solution. Thanks again.